# Python * on arguments (not args or kwargs)

Tags: python, parameters

I saw in many python functions people using a single standalone "*" parameter, but it is not args or kwargs.
I just saw an example on shutil standard lib documentation.:

```
shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)
```

I tried to google it, but only found examples about args.
What does this parameter do exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, it means that `follow_symlinks` has to be named as a parameter when the function is invoked. So you can't do `copy(mySrc, myDest, True)` - you have to do `copy(mySrc, myDest, follow_symlinks=True)`. It forces the user to name the parameter for which they are passing a value

Comment: See the last part of the top answer: "Also Python 3 adds new semantic (refer PEP 3102):" https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/6260170

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/ explains why and how it came into the fold

Comment: It looks similar to the idea of doing `a, _ = foo()`?  `_` has no practical use -- except giving an ability to collect only one item if required.